# How to exclude multiple scrolls events for section scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm facing **problem** is that even when I scroll one time, it gets scrolled multiple times automatically.

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/xyjccphb/).

So, what I want is that only one section should be scrolled when I scroll one time. When I scroll down 1 time, next section should be seen. Similarly, when I scroll up 1 time, previous section should be seen.

I tried getting help from similar based question but I didn't get one. Thanks for the help in advance.

```js
$(function(){
 var lastScrollTop = 0, timer;
 $(window).scroll(function(event){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  var windowH, scrollTop, currentSec = 0, scrollRatio, secOffset, secOffsetTop;
  scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  windowH = $(window).outerHeight();
  if (scrollTop == 0) {
   currentSec = 1;
  } else {
   scrollRatio = scrollTop/windowH;
   scrollRatio = Math.round(scrollRatio);
   currentSec = scrollRatio + 1;
  }
  secOffset = $("#sec-"+currentSec).offset();
  secOffsetTop = secOffset.top;
  
  console.log("currentSec: "+currentSec);
  
  //Stackoverflow Code
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
   if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
    // downscroll code
    console.log("DOWN DOWN DOWN!");
    //$("#sec-" + currentSec).next("section").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    var targetOffset = $("#sec-" + currentSec).next("section").offset();   
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset.top}, 1250);
   } else {
    // upscroll code
    console.log("DOWN DOWN UP!");
    //$("#sec-" + currentSec).prev("section").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    var targetOffset = $("#sec-" + currentSec).prev("section").offset();   
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset.top});
   }
  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  //Stackoverflow Code ENDS
  }, 1250);
  
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
}
#sec-1 {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}
#sec-2 {
  background-color: #47cf73;
}
#sec-3 {
  background-color: #fcd000;
}
#sec-4 {
  background-color: #b9f;
}
#sec-5 {
  background-color: #ff3c41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec-scroll" id="sec-1">Section 1 </section>
<section class="sec-scroll" id="sec-2">Section 2 </section>
<section class="sec-scroll" id="sec-3">Section 3 </section>
<section class="sec-scroll" id="sec-4">Section 4 </section>
<section class="sec-scroll" id="sec-5">Section 5 </section>
```